# How to access Cognito user attributes from a Lambda function called by API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless

I have an iOS app with an authenticated cognito user calling a lambda function through API Gateway.

I'm trying to access this user's attributes from within the lambda function (written in Python). E.g. i want to get his username to add a comment he's sending to my database.

This seems like quite a basic thing to do, and I'm surprised it's so difficult.

- I've been looking at the context & event objects passed to the lambda function, but it does not contain user attributes
- I tried to look at using boto3 to request information from cognito, but cannot find how to make it work

  I think the way to do this is to get some information from the context object, and then use the boto3 lib to connect to Cognito and request user attributes. I cannot find anywhere an example of how to do this and boto3 documentation is not very helpful.

I would very much appreciate help on this, I must be missing a very easy & obvious way to do this given how little talk there is on this issue.

Thanks